# RigExpert AntScope2 is missing Data popup

Tags: antenna-analyzer

I recently started using AntScope2 and everything was great. But all of a sudden the Data popup has disappeared. The missing popup is circled in the photo.

How do I turn it back on or get it back?  Thanks!

[image]